# inner foreach loop sorting

Tags: sort

I have the following script and i need to sort the inner foreach loop alphabetically but with no success.

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'clinical_sites',
        'tax_query' => array( 
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'research', 
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'operator' => 'AND',
                            'hide_empty' => false,
                            'terms' => $researchName
                    ),
                    array( 
                            'taxonomy' => 'country',
                            'hide_empty' => false,
                            'operator' => 'IN',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $fatherTermId 
                        ),
                    ),
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'parent' => '1'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

            $args3 = array( 
                'orderby'  => 'ID',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
                'childless' => true
            );
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'country', $args3  );
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                foreach ( $terms as $parent_term ) {


                        ?><option value="<?=$parent_term->name; ?>" data-is-parent="<?=$isparent?>" data-term_id="<?=$parent_term->term_id; ?>" ><?php echo $parent_term->name?></option><?php
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just change `'orderby' => 'ID'` to `'orderby' => 'name'` and your terms will be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @swissspidy can you post that as an answer? Comments are for clarifying questions, and I can't give you rep for a comment

Comment: @TomJNowell Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need to do is change toe `orderby` argument of your `wp_get_object_terms()` call. After all, that's what you're looping through further down.

If you change `'orderby' => 'ID'` to `'orderby' => 'name'`, your terms will be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Not working :(
I think its because of the outer while loop that loops through the posts, and i need to display the terms one by one in a dropdown menu.